# Auto-generating a closing event handler in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In the forms designer of Visual Studio 2010, you can auto-generate event handlers (mostly done by double-clicking on the control that you want an event handler created for).  However, I cannot determine how to auto-generate a closing event handler (not a closed event handler).  Can any of you VS2010 gurus show me the way?  Not sure if this matters, but this is for a Visual C# program.

To clarify, I'm looking for a way to auto-generate the closing event handler (this event happens when a user clicks the close/cancel button, but fires before the app actually closes).

Thanks!

Comment: btw, if you were the real crash override you wouldn't be asking this newb question ;)

Comment: Ha!  The world of Microsoft is new to me!  This old dog has to learn new tricks now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the window of your application and in the properties section (bottom right), click on the events tab, and then go to the Close and then type in a name of the method and it should create one for you in the code-behind.

Comment: Awesome!  The event that I was looking for is "FormClosing".  I found it just where you told me to look and after entering a name for the event handler, it auto-created just like I wanted.  Thanks so much!  As soon as the timer is up, your answer will be chosen.